# moving and deleting selected items from check box list

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I have a GUI forum with 2 buttons 
One button adds students to a check list box 
The other button adds teachers to the same check list box  until I have a small summary oif each

What I want to do is when only students are selected or when teachers are selected it moves them to a list box of some kind, maybe another checklist box

If both a student and a teacher is select it should give some sort of error like must only select students or teachers in a message box

Or my other idea If easier to do would the student button will add student to checklist box 1 & 2 
And the teacher button would add teacher to checklist box 1 & 3

Then when you select a student or teacher in one the checklist and delete/remove it, it removes them from the other checklists

For example if I select student in checkboxlist 1 and remove it then it will remove the same student in checkbox list 2

Is it possible to do any that? If so what would be the best was or easiest way to code it ?
If could give some example code then if be truely grateful

Hopefully what I'm asking is clear enough, I'm sorry if its bit and I hope the way I'm asking the question is correct

Comment: Surely it's possible. But what have you tried so far? Give us the code you met difficulties in

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't have the code on me just now but will try get it up soon as I can, I am able to delete the data that has been selected but I need to select same data from all the boxes they are in manually if I want remove them I can't seam to get it to work where if I delete a student it removes it from the other list

Comment: @naveen: I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the button, have it loop through all the checked values and add them to the other list or delete them.